# How to embed bitmap into D3js generated SVG code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Given access to suitable topojson and bitmaps, I use the topoJSON file to generate a SVG viz via D3js. Then I append a bitmap to it via :

```
// Append bitmap
    svg.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "./myimage.png")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("class", "bg");
```

But this actually just add a link toward the image. Also, when I select the dataviz DOM, and save it as SVG, I don't have the bitmap binary, but just the bitmap's link.

**Is it possible, and how to really embed my .png binary into my SVG DOM via D3js or javascript ?**

[image]

See also: https://rugger-demast.codio.io/front/_location_map-en-wikiatlas.html , where you can try to download the SVG.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the PNG to canvas and saving the dataURI by binding it as data to the svg:image element?

Comment: May be related to [How to export PNG within SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804803/)

Answer (score 2):

This example shows how to draw an image to a canvas element and use the `.toDataURL` function to get a snapshot of this canvas into a string that you can then use as the `xlink:href` attribute:

http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/707681f1f5b4a2063d6e

Comment: I got it working but generating a canvas, then a snapshot of it create new troubles to my workflow. I have some hints that loading the file, and convert the string to base 64 via `atob()` may work in a more straight forward way.

Comment: You may be right, and I'm sure there's a more efficient way, but this is the only one that I have experience with.