# How to export PNG within SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have some trouble to export my SVG which contains a PNG image in it. I'm using *D3JS* and the following code.

```
mysvg.append("image")
  .attr("width", 299)
  .attr("height", 168)
  .attr("xlink:href", "image.png")

var html = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("version", 1.1)
  .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
  .node().parentNode.innerHTML;
var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">';
d3.select("#chartRender").html(img);
```

It seems that an error occurs: `Namespace prefix xlink for href on image is not defined`.
The PNG image is correctly displayed in the SVG container but not in `#chartRender`

Any idea ?

**Update 1 :
Drawing the image in a canvas works**

```
canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas").attr("id", "newCanvas")
  .attr("width", "200px").attr("height", "100px").node()
context = canvas.getContext('2d')
imageObj = new Image()
imageObj.src = params.url
imageObj.onload = -> context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0)
```

But displaying the datas show empty content :(

```
imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
d3.select("body").append("img").datum(imageData).attr("src", (d)-> return d)
d3.select("svg").append("image").datum(imageData).attr("height", "100")
  .attr("width", "200").attr("xlink:href", (d)-> return d)
```

Comment: May be related to [D3js: how to truly embed a bitmap into D3js generated SVG code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795776/)

Comment: If you reference an svg from an <img> element all external references get blocked by the browsers for security reasons. You need to make the png into a data uri to get this to work in that particular scenario, or use an <iframe> or <object> to reference the svg. See e.g http://stackoverflow.com/a/20816406/109374.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `xmlns:xlink` to your svg tag.

It should look like this:

```
<svg width="xxx" height="yyy" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

So just do...

```
.attr("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
```

### UPDATE

I created a **[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qufosa/1/edit)** to help us with this. It is working just fine.

```
var mysvg = d3.select('#mysvg');

var src = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';

mysvg.append("image")
  .attr("width", 350)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("xlink:href", src);

var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;

document.getElementById("target").appendChild(img);
```

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Ty for your answer. It doesn't seems to work. The exported graph is now empty :( If I remove the image from the SVG (in the code) then it's working but without the image (obviously) :(

Comment: does your image have a relative path?

Comment: yes. it's in the root directory and called: image.png

Comment: try set an absolute path ... maybe that's your problem ... anyway, it's another issue right? if it is, then you should post an other question.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I have added what you suggest and still the same problem `Uncaught NamespaceError: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' on 'Element': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' is an invalid namespace for attributes.`

Comment: I've updated my question. It's definitely not the path since it can be draw in the Canvas container.